# how to architect better for a social media app using stream builder and bloc pattern

Tags: list, flutter, stream, bloc, stream-builder

currently am using the direct API call and map data into a list and use a callback function to change the list properties.
my API model is

```
        class UserProfileResponse {
                  int status;
                  String message;
                  Data data; }
                      
        class Data {
              UserDetails userDetails;
              List<Post> posts;
              String followers;
              String following; }

        class Post {
          String id;
          String userId;
          String post;
          String imagepath;
          String location;
          DateTime postDate;
          String likes;
          String status;
          String active;
          String inactive;
          String createdBy;
          String postType;
          String userLiked;
          String isGroup;
          String videoLink;
          String comments;
          String shares;
          String thumbnail; }

  class UserDetails {
      String username;
      String email;
      String id;
      String profilePicture;
      String bio;
      String address;
      String mobile; }
```

how can I use bloc pattern for an instantaneous update of like and unlike while it needs API call, currently now I use set state and update the list and then call an API request to backend changes, it is cumbersome with callbacks?
Is it possible to architect it with API response streams and list data streams concurrently for eg like, unlike option so I can update without delay in the network?

Comment: you should atleast try yourself, and if you face any problem then ask for help on SO 
see https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

Answer (score 0):

Using streamprovider might help you with that, but be sure to not call the provider multiple times if so, you will be making unnecessary calls to the API.